# Flows show failed in anypoint platform

Tags: mule, esb, anypoint-studio, mule-cluster

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yefps.png)

I have deployed one service on prem and configured it in runtime manager of anypoint platform.I can see the service started in anypoint platform. But if I click the service then it has 5-6 flows among which 3 flows show status as 'Failed' but it still works. Why is that happening, is it a issue?

Comment: Nobody can guess and provide you with an answer here until and unless you provide full details of your flows, issues you are facing and full stack trace of the error/exception you are getting ...

Comment: I dont get any exceptions. Infact the services is deployed successfully. But  if I check the flow management in the runtime manager there i can see the status as failed. I have attached a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

This is a defect in the ARM flows feature.  Flows generated by APIKit show as failed, even when working.  The Jira ticket mentions SOAP apikit, but I've seen the same behavior for REST apikit as well.

See https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-12421.